# woocommerce plugin remove item

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i am new to woocommerce, actually i want to customize product display so i manually parse products from database i want to remove an item from woocommerce cart through product id, i have found this function,

$woocommerce->cart->get_remove_url($cart_item_key); in core woocommerce cart class, but i am unable to understand what i have to write in $cart_item_key, i have tried to product id or product url in it but its not removing product item from cart, can somebody help me please what i have write in this variable $cart_item_key,

/*** Gets the url to remove an item from the cart.
*
* @return string url to page
*/

its description of that function, i have tried using full url of product page and also slug

Regards

Arsalan

Answer (score 3):

I know its an old post but it may help someone.

```
foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
  if($cart_item['product_id'] == $your_product_id)
  $woocommerce->cart->get_remove_url($cart_item_key); 
}
```

Hope its helps..